# parameter type has "T=", what's the meaning

Tags: scala

In spark JdbcRDD scala, it has the following code. And it has a parameter like

```
mapRow: (ResultSet) => T = JdbcRDD.resultSetToObjectArray _
```

What's the meaning of "T=" in that parameter? Why not just

```
mapRow: (ResultSet) => JdbcRDD.resultSetToObjectArray _
```

The code is:

```
class JdbcRDD[T: ClassTag](
    sc: SparkContext,
    getConnection: () => Connection,
    sql: String,
    lowerBound: Long,
    upperBound: Long,
    numPartitions: Int,
    mapRow: (ResultSet) => T = JdbcRDD.resultSetToObjectArray _)

object JdbcRDD {
  def resultSetToObjectArray(rs: ResultSet) = {
    Array.tabulate[Object](rs.getMetaData.getColumnCount)(i => rs.getObject(i + 1))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whole `(ResultSet) => T` part is the *type* of the parameter. It means that `mapRow` parameter is a function from `ResultSet` into `T`.

In your example, it is a parameter with *default* value, similar to

```
def foo(justAnInt : Int = 4) = ???
```

which is the part after `=` in the parameter list.

So, you get `parameterName : type = defaultVal`, as you might notice, it is directly:

```
mapRow : (ResultSet) => T = ...
```

In plain words, the parameter is a function from `ResultSet` into `T` with default value of `JdbcRDD.resultSetToObjectArray` method converted into function (hence the trailing underscore).

Comment: Thanks.  Is there difference between "ResultSet => T " and "(ResultSet) => T "?  Is () is must?

Comment: @DanielWu In this case, it doesn't matter. But when you have functions with multiple parameters, you can have them tupled (e.g. `(Int, Int) => Int`) or curried (e.g. `Int => Int => Int`), which makes a difference.